# Pause epic when criteria met, then emit buffered action when criteria complete

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am working on an application whereby I we periodically persist information to a server when a user navigates between pages.

We currently do this by scheduling a "persist" action, which propagates a sequenced number of events, before finishing with a "persist_end" action. Currently, if a user navigates quickly, these grouped actions can intercept each other, resulting in various problems. I thought I could buffer the starting action and wait until the ending action was executed.

I've created a similar example using the ping-pong example from Redux-Observables site: https://codepen.io/dualcyclone/pen/GOZRxW?editors=0011

```
const actionPauser = new BehaviorSubject(false);

const pingEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(PING)
      .do(action => console.log(action)) // check if action caught by epic
      .buffer(actionPauser.asObservable().filter(paused => !paused))
      .do(eh => console.log('buffered? ',eh)) // check if buffered actions is occurring
      .do(() => actionPauser.next(true)) // tell pauser to pause
      .map((buf) => buf[buf.length-1])
      .filter(action => action !== undefined)
      .delay(1000)
      .mapTo({ type: PONG });

const pauseEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(PONG)
      .delay(1000)
      .do(() => actionPauser.next(false)) // tell pauser to not pause
      .mapTo({ type: PING });
```

The premise is similar, I am allowing the user to press the "start PING" button as often as they like, the epic that is listening to this should check to see if there is a ping action currently occuring (by the "actionPauser" BehaviorSubject), and queue any actions until a previous ping action has completed.

The epic should emit the most recent buffered action, so it filters the buffered list then passes through the latest one.

What I can't seem to understand is - the console log to indicate how many buffered actions there are fires as soon as the page loads; which may indicate a problem with the way this is built - am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like the [`audit`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-audit) operator would be useful to you.

Comment: @cartant Thanks, your suggestion did exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, whilst the output of the actions isn't exactly desirable (theres not really much I can do about it given the starting action is emitted by a user event), the suggestion Cartant recommended actually does precisely what I need.

[Audit](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-audit):

> Ignores source values for a duration determined by another Observable, then emits the most recent value from the source Observable, then repeats this process.

In essence, this allows me to ignore multiple emitted 'PING' events whilst one is currently ongoing. It will then continue the execution of the last most recent 'PING' event, so the output we see is as follows:

```
(click) PING (click) PING (click) PING (click) PING PONG DONE PONG DONE
```

The first and last 'PING' actions are the only ones propagated through the Epic, so we see two final PONG actions, both followed by a DONE action.

So, here is the answered example (as also seen on my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/dualcyclone/pen/GOZRxW?editors=0011))

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PING)
    .audit(() => actionPauser.filter(paused => !paused))
    .do(() => actionPauser.next(true))
    .delay(1000)
    .mapTo({ type: PONG });

const pauseEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PONG)
    .delay(1000)
    .mapTo({ type: DONE })
    .do(() => actionPauser.next(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) might work well in this case.

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output Observable, in a serialized fashion waiting for each one to complete before merging the next.

So in the case below, only one timer is running at a time. Any PINGs that come in while the previous is still waiting will be buffered.

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PING)
    .concatMap(() =>
      Observable.timer(1000)
        .mapTo({ type: PONG })
    );
```

https://jsbin.com/gocezut/edit?js,output

```
(rapidly click four times)
PING
PING
PING
PING
(1000ms pass)
PONG
(1000ms pass)
PONG
(1000ms pass)
PONG
(1000ms pass)
PONG
```

---

Remember that most redux-observable questions can be reframed to just be regular RxJS questions, broadening the resources and help you can find. That's the beauty of redux-observable: it's almost entirely just regular RxJS patterns.

Comment: I'll try this out; but in my specific use-case, the "ping" indicates the start of a sequence of other actions, the last of which finishes and emits the "pong" action. So in your example, I could potentially delay it to start the  next action, but ideally I need to prevent the next "ping" if a "pong" hasn't occurred. So, the output should be: (click) ping (click) (click) (click) pong ping pong (ideally I want to filter so that only the most recent not executed action is allowed to propagate)

Comment: to clarify, are you saying you want to prevent/buffer PINGs? That's not possible with redux-observable (intentionally) because that means modifying the intent of actions dispatched from your UI. Instead, use the intent action to signal the start of potentially other actions. If it makes it more clear, you can rename PING to something like BUFFERED_PING, then the epic could potentially emit PING immediately or wait until it has received PONG to start.

Comment: This often trips people up when they're relatively new to redux-observable/redux-saga. Just remember that actions dispatched from the UI directly should always be _intent_, which may or may not actually cause the  desired side effect right away depending on the desired business logic in your epics.